# How do I format single array nested JSON data and print it a browser using AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I need help in formatting single array nested JSON data and displaying it in a browser.
My main issue is picking a single id of an array of data, formatting it, and printing it on a browser.

I have so far succefully print only array using `$('#data').html( JSON.stringify(response));`, but no idea on how to print
or display formatted JSON on a browser.

`<div id="data"></div>`

```
<script>
let response = [
    {"person":[{"id":1,"Name":"ben","Location":"uk","History":"Born 1990","Status":"male"}]}
];


$('#data').html( JSON.stringify(response));

</script>
```

Kindly

Comment: did you want to pretty-print it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

can't get your question properly, Are You asking about how to display the data inside the array using an specific id?

if it is the question, then try the below code,

```
$('#data').html(JSON.stringify(response[0].person[0]))
```